# Weird results in c# app game

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

For an internship project I'm making an app based on Foley sound effects. I made a game for it. One button generates the effect, one plays the sound and four buttons for possible awnsers.

Somehow, the text displays ('helaas' and 'juist!') aren't consistent. The awnser could be right and it will display 'helaas', but when clicken multiple times, it will display 'juist!'. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here?

```
int kiesnummer()
        {
            Random randomSound = new Random();
            int theSound = randomSound.Next(1, 4);
            return theSound;
        }
        NewSound.Click += delegate
        {
            kiesnummer();

            if (kiesnummer() == 1)
            {

                welk.Text = "Open haard";

            }
            else if (kiesnummer() == 2)
            {

                welk.Text = "Regen";

            }
            else if (kiesnummer() == 3)
            {

                welk.Text = "Hondenpootjes op hout";

            }
            else if (kiesnummer() == 4)
            {
                welk.Text = "Paardenhoeven op beton";

            }
        };

        Play.Click += delegate
        {

            if (kiesnummer() == 1)
            {
                _chips.Start();

            }
            else if (kiesnummer() == 2)
            {
                _rain.Start();

            }
            else if (kiesnummer() == 3)
            {
                _doggo.Start();

            }
            else if(kiesnummer() == 4)
            {
                _koko.Start();

            }
        };

        //Parameters aan functie koppelen bij klikken op de knop
        Aw1.Click += delegate
        {
            kiesknop(1);
        };

        Aw2.Click += delegate
        {
            kiesknop(2);
        };

        Aw3.Click += delegate
        {
            kiesknop(3);
        };

        Aw4.Click += delegate
        {
            kiesknop(4);
        };


        //Beoordelen of keuze juist of onjuist is
        bool kiesknop(int knop)
        {
            if (knop == kiesnummer())
            { 
                end.Text = "Juist!";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                end.Text = "Helaas!";
                return false;
            }


        }
```

(I left the button and media declerations out, since it didn't seem relevant)

Comment: You are creating a new random number every time you call `kiesnummer`. If you want to compare guesses with played sounds you have to store somewehre what sound was played instead of calling `kiesnummer` again, which will create a new random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `kiesnummer();` in every if condition will give you different results as it generates new random value every time.

Call it once and use its value through-out:

```
int value = kiesnummer();

if (value == 1)
{

    welk.Text = "Open haard";

}
else if (value == 2)
{

    welk.Text = "Regen";

}
else if (value) == 3)
{

    welk.Text = "Hondenpootjes op hout";

}
else if (value == 4)
{
    welk.Text = "Paardenhoeven op beton";

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that!